# Can not use Google Barcode scanner

Tags: android, android-vision

I tried Google barcode-reader from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision

This example doesn't work. When I tab to screen it always detect

> "no barcode detected"

Debug reason :

```
private boolean onTap(float rawX, float rawY) {

    //TODO: use the tap position to select the barcode.
    BarcodeGraphic graphic = mGraphicOverlay.getFirstGraphic();
    Barcode barcode = null;
    if (graphic != null) {
        barcode = graphic.getBarcode();
        if (barcode != null) {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra(BarcodeObject, barcode);
            setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "barcode data is null");
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG,"no barcode detected");
    }
    return barcode != null;
}
```

`graphic` variable is always `Null`

See the image:

[image: Image on android studio]

Anyone faced this problem? Can you let me know how to resolve it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: What hardware are you testing this on?

Answer (score 2):

So I guest you are new to Android Mobile Vision, in the new version of Google Play services (v9) they temporarily disabled the feature due to a serious bug in that feature, you can check the release note here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90

Answer (score 2):

As @Vietnt134 have already answered, Android Mobile Vision is temporarily disabled.

You can follow this topic to know if something knew came up:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/98

People are pretty mad with Google about this. I hope they solve this quickly.

Answer (score 1):

`getFirstGraphic` returns null whenever no graphics have been added to the overlay; in the barcode example, this is when no barcodes have been detected in the frame.

Check if `barcodeDetector.isOperational()` is returning false in BarcodeCaptureActivity.java.  If it's returning false, has for several minutes, and you aren't in a low storage condition, there's a very good chance this is because of a current service outage.

More details can be found here:  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/98 We'll update that issue as soon as we have a resolution.